# windowsに導入したmysql80のrootパスワードを初期化したいが手順通りにできない

Tags: mysql

windowsに導入したmysqlにrootパスワードを設定したのですが忘れたので初期化したい・・・が手順通りにできないです。

手順はこちらを参考にしました。
https://tech.adseed.co.jp/20201210185248dt6

こちらの手順の以下の所

```
MySQLに接続
別で新たにコマンドプロンプトを開いて
mysql -u root mysql
これでMySQLに接続できます
```

ここでまだパスワードを求められているので、
iniファイルにパスワードを求められないオプション具体的には以下のような形に追記してもパスワードが求められてしまいます。

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

まずはパスワードを初期化したいのですが、
解決として最悪、mysqlの作り直しやdockerコンテナで持つなどを考えてます。

Comment: root のパスワードを設定したけど分からなくなったから初期化したい…という事でしょうか？デフォルトでは "何も設定されていない" とあります。参考: [root のパスワードをリセットする方法 | MySQL 8.0 リファレンスマニュアル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: 設定を変更した後に mysqld は再起動していますか？